# How to share an Image and Text directly to Whats App in Android-java,using Glide library

Tags: android

How can one share a complete loaded image set in an ImageView along side with text to whats app using intents and Glide.....I looked a lot but i only found for Picasso Library here is the [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/) or if the link is dead google this phrase :

> Sharing Content with Intents · codepath_android_guides Wiki.htm

Comment: Crosslink https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1439

Answer (score 3):

i have found a  working solution for my problem after reading around on glide and on cache in Picasso , so the logic i got to was :
**When glide loads the image successfully then the  set the bitmap int the image view then also since the image has been cached make use of  the cached image and use the image as if its a normal image then pass it to an sharing intent that you or i would have defined.**
the code is: EventfaceImage **is the imageview i defined,**

```
Glide.with(context).load(uri).asBitmap().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .dontAnimate().into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(EventfaceImage) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(final Bitmap bmp, GlideAnimation anim) {
            share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            EventfaceImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    menu_float.close(true);
                    prepareShareIntent(bmp);
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
            super.onLoadFailed(e, errorDrawable);
        }
    });
```

then the  **prepareShareIntent();** method

```
private void prepareShareIntent(Bitmap bmp) {
    Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(bmp); // see previous remote images section
    // Construct share intent as described above based on bitmap

    shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getResources().getString(R.string.shared_via)  );
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Opportunity"));

}
private Uri getLocalBitmapUri(Bitmap bmp) {
    Uri bmpUri = null;
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmpUri;
}
```

**This works for me in API 22 .So i hope this will help someone  but also i have not tested in all the api in android  if doesnt please let me know and i will see what i can hack. also feel free to better the code and share whats working for you too**

Comment: Are you using SD Card to store your images externally?

Comment: @nocholla yes you could store on sd card but Android defaults would be the primary memory where it will cache in most cases the phone memory especially in Android 22 + if you want to store on sd card cache you would need permission in Android 23 + at run time.

Answer (score 0):

The above method has been deprecated in favour of below

```
Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(url)
                .into(new Target<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

                    }
                });
```